# Without debug mode UnsafePointer withMemoryRebound will gives wrong value

Tags: swift, byte

Here I am trying to concatenate 5 bytes into the single Integer value, I am getting an issue with `UnsafePointer withMemoryRebound` method. 
when I am debugging and checking logs it will gives the correct value. But when I try without debug, it will give the wrong value.(4 out of 5 times wrong value). I got confuses on this API. Is it correct way I am using?

case 1:

```
let data = [UInt8](rowData) // rowData is type of Data class
let totalKM_BitsArray = [data[8],data[7],data[6],data[5],data[4]]
self.totalKm = UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray).withMemoryRebound(to:UInt64.self, capacity: 1) {$0.pointee}
```

case 2:

Below code will work for both   Enable or Disable debug mode And gives the correct value.

```
    let byte0 : UInt64 = UInt64(data[4])<<64
    let byte1 : UInt64 = UInt64(data[5])<<32
    let byte2 : UInt64 = UInt64(data[6])<<16
    let byte3 : UInt64 = UInt64(data[7])<<8
    let byte4 : UInt64 = UInt64(data[8])
    self.totalKm = byte0 | byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4
```

Please suggest me  UnsafePointer way of using? Why will this issue come?

Addtional infomation :

```
let totalKm : UInt64
```

`let data = [UInt8](rowData)` //  data contain [100, 200, 28, 155, 0, 0, 0, 26, 244, 0, 0, 0, 45, 69, 0, 0, 0, 4, 246]

`let totalKM_BitsArray = [data[8],data[7],data[6],data[5],data[4]]` // contain   [ 244,26,0,0,0]

```
self.totalKm = UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray).withMemoryRebound(to:UInt64.self, capacity: 1) {$0.pointee}
```

// when print log gives correct value, when run on device give wrong 3544649566089386 like this.

```
 self.totalKm = byte0 | byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4
```

//    output is  6900 This is correct as expected

Comment: Also note that shifting a `UInt64` by `<< 64` will always yield 0, as you're shifting all of the bits away.

Comment: Thanks for replay @Hamish
`let totalKm : UInt64 `
`let data = [UInt8](rowData)` //  data contain [100, 200, 28, 155, 0, 0, 0, 26, 244, 0, 0, 0, 45, 69, 0, 0, 0, 4, 246] 
let totalKM_BitsArray = [data[8],data[7],data[6],data[5],data[4]] // contain   [ 244,26,0,0,0]
self.totalKm = UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray).withMemoryRebound(to:UInt64.self, capacity: 1) {$0.pointee}
 // when print log gives correct value, when run on device give wrong 3544649566089386 like this. 
 self.totalKm = byte0 | byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4 
//    output is  6900 This is correct as expected

Comment: Thanks; could you please [edit] the question with these additional details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with this approach:

```
let data = [UInt8](rowData) // rowData is type of Data class
let totalKM_BitsArray = [data[8], data[7], data[6], data[5], data[4]]
self.totalKm = UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray)
                 .withMemoryRebound(to:UInt64.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee }
```

- Dereferencing `UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray)` is *undefined behaviour*, as the pointer to `totalKM_BitsArray`'s buffer is only temporarily valid for the duration of the initialiser call (hopefully at some point in the future Swift will warn on such constructs).
- You're trying to bind only 5 instances of `UInt8` to `UInt64`, so the remaining 3 instances will be garbage.
- You can only `withMemoryRebound(_:)` between types of the same size and stride; which is not the case for `UInt8` and `UInt64`.
- It's dependant on the endianness of your platform; `data[8]` will be the least significant byte on a little endian platform, but the most significant byte on a big endian platform.

Your implementation with bit shifting avoids all of these problems (and is generally the safer way to go as you don't have to consider things like layout compatibility, alignment, and pointer aliasing).

However, assuming that you just wanted to pad out your data with zeroes for the most significant bytes, with `rowData[4]` to `rowData[8]` making up the rest of the less significant bytes, then you'll want your bit-shifting implementation to look like this:

```
let rowData = Data([
  100, 200, 28, 155, 0, 0, 0, 26, 244, 0, 0, 0, 45, 69, 0, 0, 0, 4, 246
])

let byte0 = UInt64(rowData[4]) << 32
let byte1 = UInt64(rowData[5]) << 24
let byte2 = UInt64(rowData[6]) << 16
let byte3 = UInt64(rowData[7]) << 8
let byte4 = UInt64(rowData[8])
let totalKm = byte0 | byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | byte4
print(totalKm) // 6900
```

or, iteratively:

```
var totalKm: UInt64 = 0
for byte in rowData[4 ... 8] {
  totalKm = (totalKm << 8) | UInt64(byte)
}
print(totalKm) // 6900
```

or, using `reduce(_:_:)`:

```
let totalKm = rowData[4 ... 8].reduce(0 as UInt64) { accum, byte in
  (accum << 8) | UInt64(byte)
}
print(totalKm) // 6900
```

We can even abstract this into an extension on `Data` in order to make it easier to load such fixed width integers:

```
enum Endianness {
  case big, little
}

extension Data {
  /// Loads the type `I` from the buffer. If there aren't enough bytes to
  /// represent `I`, the most significant bits are padded with zeros.
  func load<I : FixedWidthInteger>(
    fromByteOffset offset: Int = 0, as type: I.Type, endianness: Endianness = .big
  ) -> I {
    let (wholeBytes, spareBits) = I.bitWidth.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 8)
    let bytesToRead = Swift.min(count, spareBits == 0 ? wholeBytes : wholeBytes + 1)

    let range = startIndex + offset ..< startIndex + offset + bytesToRead
    let bytes: Data
    switch endianness {
    case .big:
      bytes = self[range]
    case .little:
      bytes = Data(self[range].reversed())
    }

    return bytes.reduce(0) { accum, byte in
      (accum << 8) | I(byte)
    }
  }
}
```

We're doing a bit of extra work here in order to we read the right number of bytes, as well as being able to handle both big and little endian. But now that we've written it, we can simply write:

```
let totalKm = rowData[4 ... 8].load(as: UInt64.self)
print(totalKm) // 6900
```

Note that so far I've assumed that the `Data` you're getting is zero-indexed. This is safe for the above examples, but [isn't necessarily safe](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5300) depending on where the data is coming from (as it could be a slice). You *should* be able to do `Data(someUnknownDataValue)` in order to get a zero-indexed data value that you can work with, although unfortunately I don't believe there's any documentation that guarantees this.

In order to ensure you're correctly indexing an arbitrary `Data` value, you can define the following extension in order to perform the correct offsetting in the case where you're dealing with a slice:

```
extension Data {
  subscript(offset offset: Int) -> Element {
    get { return self[startIndex + offset] }
    set { self[startIndex + offset] = newValue }
  }

  subscript<R : RangeExpression>(
    offset range: R
  ) -> SubSequence where R.Bound == Index {
    get {
      let concreteRange = range.relative(to: self)
      return self[startIndex + concreteRange.lowerBound ..<
                  startIndex + concreteRange.upperBound]
    }
    set {
      let concreteRange = range.relative(to: self)
      self[startIndex + concreteRange.lowerBound ..<
           startIndex + concreteRange.upperBound] = newValue
    }
  }
}
```

Which you can use then call as e.g `data[offset: 4]` or `data[offset: 4 ... 8].load(as: UInt64.self)`.

---

Finally it's worth noting that while you could *probably* implement this as a re-interpretation of bits by using `Data`'s `withUnsafeBytes(_:)` method:

```
let rowData = Data([
  100, 200, 28, 155, 0, 0, 0, 26, 244, 0, 0, 0, 45, 69, 0, 0, 0, 4, 246
])

let kmData = Data([0, 0, 0] + rowData[4 ... 8])
let totalKm = kmData.withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
  UInt64(bigEndian: buffer.load(as: UInt64.self))
}
print(totalKm) // 6900
```

This is relying on `Data`'s buffer being 64-bit aligned, which isn't guaranteed. You'll get a runtime error for attempting to load a misaligned value, for example:

```
let data = Data([0x01, 0x02, 0x03])
let i = data[1...].withUnsafeBytes { buffer in
  buffer.load(as: UInt16.self) // Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer
}
```

By loading individual `UInt8` values instead and performing bit shifting, we can avoid such alignment issues (however if/when `UnsafeMutableRawPointer` [supports unaligned loads](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0107-unsaferawpointer.md#future-improvements-and-planned-additive-api), this will no longer be an issue).

Comment: Thanks for answer, when i am tried with  let totalKM_BitsArray = [data[8],data[7],data[6],data[5],data[4],0,0,0], it will gives correct value, I think its take garbage value.

Comment: @JoyalClifford Yup, though note that you're still not *guaranteed* to get the correct result using `UnsafePointer(totalKM_BitsArray).withMemoryRebound(to:UInt64.self, capacity: 1) { $0.pointee }` due to the other issues I mentioned.

Comment: @JoyalClifford I added a couple more ways of going about this by bit shifting, as really that's the more foolproof way of doing this.